# Using storyboard unwinds, how do I take data from the view controller I'm returning from and use it in the view controller I returned to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have everything implemented, and the following method that fires when I return to the source view controller:

```
- (IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    ...
}
```

I want to take the value from the UITextField in the view I'm returning from, and set a value in my source view (or the view that calls this method) to the value of that UITextField.

I tried this:

```
- (IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddTextViewController *returnedFromViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *inputtedText = returnedFromViewController.textField.text;
    self.foo = inputtedText;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
[RootViewController textField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc0250
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController textField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dc0250'
```

What am I doing wrong in that code above? There's hardly any documentation on this, so it's very hard to search around myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong controller. You want the segue's `sourceViewController`, not the `destinationViewController`. Otherwise, you're doing it all correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement a protocol / delegate. The delegate will handle any requests from your destination view controller and send the data back to your source view controller.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: Why is this better than the built in way of doing it?

Comment: Delegates are the preferred way to handle actions such as this. Not everything uses a segue as well. It's a very good thing to understand proper usage of delegates if they are unclear. Run through a few examples and they won't seem as complex as they appear at first sight.  http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using unwind segues in this situation. Delegates would work as well, but in some cases, unwind segues can even be a cleaner solution.

Comment: It's not that there is anything wrong with using source/dest. It's the simple fact that he said "(or the view that calls this method)". In that case, the source viewcontroller may not be the segues view. Learning proper usage of delegates along with segues covers both scenarios.